# How to print parts of a regular expression into a .txt file

Tags: java, regex, text-files, expression

I am working on a project where i have to parse through text files and pull relevant information from them to work with later.

I have created a regular expression to match the lines of text that have the relevant data, but I'm unsure how to pull the relevant information from the line and dump it into a new text file.

Here's a sample from the text file i'm parsing:

```
[  5] local 10.170.150.195 port 42507 connected with 184.72.63.139 port 5001
[  4] local 10.170.150.195 port 42506 connected with 184.72.63.139 port 500
[  1]  0.0- 1.0 sec  0.00 KBytes  50.00 Kbits/sec
```

In this sample the relevant information is "0.0- 1.0 sec" and 50.00 Kbits/sec.

Here's my regular expression:

```
[  [0-6]]  0.0- 1.0 sec  0.00 KBytes  [0-9]*.[0-9][0-9] Kbits/sec
```

Sorry if this is a trivial question, I'm fairly new to java...this is day 3...
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your input file using FileReader/BufferedReader.

   ```
   FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
   ```
2. Open your output file using FileWriter/BufferedWriter

   ```
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.txt");
   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
   ```
3. Read one line at a time in `while loop` using Buffered reader into a String

   ```
   String lineString = null;
   while((lineString= br.readLine())!= null){
         //....
    }
   ```
4. Within `while loop`, match the read string against your regex

   ```
   Pattern pattern = 
   Pattern.compile("\\[  [0-6]\\]  (0.0- 1.0 sec)  0.00 KBytes  ([0-9]*.[0-9][0-9] Kbits/sec)");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lineString);
   if(matcher .matches()){
      //....
   }
   ```
5. If match found, write the string in output file using you Buffered writer

   ```
       bw.write(lineString);
   ```
6. Close all the readers/writers open.

   ```
       bw.close();
       fw.close();
       br.close();
       fr.close();
   ```

**EDIT:**  Sample code style 1 as below:

```
    String regex = "\\[  [0-6]\\]  (0.0- 1.0 sec)  0.00 KBytes  ([0-9]*.[0-9][0-9] Kbits/sec)";
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    String lineString = null;
    while((lineString= br.readLine())!= null && 
                  !lineString.equals("Starting Test 2: Iperf TCP East....")){
        if(lineString.matches(regex)){
            bw.write(lineString);
        }
    }
    bw.close();
    fw.close();
    br.close();
    fr.close();
```

Sample Code Style 2 as below:

```
 FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.txt");

 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

 Pattern pattern = 
    Pattern.compile("\\[  [0-6]\\]  (0.0- 1.0 sec)  0.00 KBytes  ([0-9]*.[0-9][0-9] Kbits/sec)");

    String lineString = null;
    while((lineString= br.readLine())!= null && !lineString.equals("Starting Test 2: Iperf TCP East....")){
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lineString);
        if(matcher.matches()){
            bw.write(lineString);
        }
    }
    bw.close();
    fw.close();
    br.close();
    fr.close();
```

All the best!

Comment: thanks for the response, and thank you for explaining the code. I am having a bit more trouble. I didnt mention that the code needed to stop part way through the file but i figured i could do it myself. i modified the while loop to read `while((lineString= br.readLine())!= "Starting Test 2: Iperf TCP East....")` but when it runs it doesn't seem to care about the arguement and continues to EOF where it gives `java.lang.NullPointerException` . When i check output.txt it is an empty file

Comment: @DonaldWillis You can't compare string using `==` operator. Use `equals()` method instead. ALso please don't remove the null check as once the reading is done, it will be null and give you `NullPointerException`. It should be written as : `while((lineString= br.readLine())!= null && !lineString.equals("Starting Test 2: Iperf TCP East...."))`.

Comment: that solves that issue, but nothing is being written to the output file. i thought it was my regular expression that was creating the issue so i appended it to `[  [0-6]]  0.0- 1.0 sec  [0-9]*.[0-9][0-9] KBytes  [0-9]*.[0-9][0-9] Kbits/sec` and i checked to make sure it would work here [link]http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html and it does, however i'm still not getting anything in the output file.

Comment: Use regex as `\\[  [0-6]\\]  (0.0- 1.0 sec)  0.00 KBytes  ([0-9]*.[0-9][0-9] Kbits/sec)`. I updated the answer with two sample codes. Please check.

Comment: adding the slashes solved part of the matching problem, there was another issue with my regular expression, but I've corrected that. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You would use parenthesis to capture the required groups, and then print those group to output.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[  [0-6]\\]  (0.0- 1.0 sec)  0.00 KBytes  ([0-9]*.[0-9][0-9] Kbits/sec)");

    String line = "[  1]  0.0- 1.0 sec  0.00 KBytes  50.00 Kbits/sec";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "\t" + matcher.group(2));
    }
```

Here `pattern` object is your regular expression, you would reuse it for all your lines. For each line of file you create a new `matcher` and pass it the line. Then if the line matched the regular expression, you print the capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a unix terminal or grep, this one line command should do the trick.

`grep "[  [0-6]]  0.0- 1.0 sec  0.00 KBytes  [0-9]*.[0-9][0-9] Kbits/sec" yourfile > newfile.txt`

The newfile.txt will have all lines from yourfile that match the regex pattern